# Not inserting on the final table, what am I not catching?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to insert some data into some tables. I am creating one submission (everytime this procedure is run) but there can be multiple values in the 2nd and 3rd tables. When I run the procedure, the entry is successfully created in calculation and value but doesn't show up in the rel table (calculation_value) for some odd reason. . Did i close something too soon? Thanks in advance.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE AGGREGATE IS
  Cursor c1 is
select sum(value_tx) AS sum_of_Values
, v.unit_cd
, v.hr_utc
, v.data_date
, ff.form_field_tx
, ff.form_field_id
, v.hr_num
, v.hr
, s.respondent_id
, vba.entity_id
, vba.acronym
, vba.name
, v.DATA_CODE
, v.utc_offset
, vba.time_zone
, vba.time_zone_offset
, vba.dst_observed
from value v
join submission_value sv on v.value_id = sv.value_id
join form_field ff on sv.form_field_id = ff.form_field_id
join submission s on sv.submission_id = s.submission_id
join respondent sr on s.RESPONDENT_ID = sr.respondent_id
join v_b_a vba on sr.entity_id = vba.entity_id
where form_field_tx = 'T'
group by vba.Entity_id, v.Data_date, v.Hr_num, s.respondent_id, ff.form_Field_tx, ff.form_field_id, v.hr_utc, v.Unit_cd, vba.acronym, vba.name,     v.DATA_CODE, v.hr, v.utc_offset, vba.time_zone, vba.time_zone_offset, vba.dst_observed;

  l_var c1%ROWTYPE;
  v_value_id value.value_id%type;
  v_calculation_id calculation.calculation_id%type;
    BEGIN
      OPEN c1;
      FETCH c1 into l_var;
          insert into calculation (calculation_id, respondent_id, calculation_dt, calculation_name_tx, Calculation_Arguments_Tx, create_dt, create_user_id, modify_dt, modify_user_id, effective_dt, inactive_dt, publication_issue_id, entity_id)
                  values (null, get_respondent_id(0,' Same', trunc(sysdate)), sysdate, sysdate, 'SUM_DEMAND', sysdate, '1', null, null, null, null, null, null)
                  returning calculation_id into v_calculation_id;
LOOP
   FETCH c1 into l_var;
   EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
      insert into value (value_id, product_id, data_source_id, unit_cd, value_tx, utc_offset, data_date, hr_utc, hr, hr_num, data_code, create_dt, create_user_id, modify_dt, modify_user_id, effective_dt, inactive_dt)
                     values (null, '111', '777', 'NA', l_var.sum_of_values, l_var.utc_offset, l_var.data_date, l_var.hr_utc, l_var.hr, l_var.hr_num, l_var.data_code, sysdate, '1', null, null, null, null)
                     returning value_id into v_value_id;
     insert into calculation_value (calculation_value_id, calculation_id, value_id, form_field_id, create_dt, create_user_id, modify_dt, modify_user_id, effective_Dt, inactive_dt)
                                values (null, v_calculation_id, v_value_id, l_var.form_field_id, sysdate, '1', null, null, null, null);

   END LOOP;
   CLOSE c1;
END AGGREGATE;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what you are saying. What is the "rel table (submission_value)"? What is "submission" that, by your words, is being inserted? Your *words* say one think, while your code suggests something different (i.e. tables calculation, value, calculation_value) - nothing like "rel" or "submission". BTW, why do you insert the first record fetched by the cursor into one table, but the second and all subsequent into the second and the third table? Maybe it is OK, just looks strange. Looking at the code, I don't see a reason why insert into the 2nd table works, but 3rd not.

Comment: sorry, i meant calculation not submission. I changed the question as needed. What i am trying to do is, every time a proc is run i will insert a row into calculation. However, there are multiple values correlated with a calculation. So for one row in a calculation, there will be multiple rows for value and (in turn) calculation_value inserted after the insert into the calculation table is first completed. Is my syntax wrong if that is what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: This sounds like a master-detail relationship (where *calculation* is master and *value* and *calculation_value* being details). If that's so, I wouldn't use the same cursor for both master and detail, but one (maybe not even a cursor, but a simple SELECT statement) for master and another for details.  On the other hand, do you really need a cursor? Can't you just INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM? Also, is this your real code? Is there, perhaps, any EXCEPTION which handles WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL or something like that? If so, remove it.

Comment: I don't have any exceptions in my original code. So it seems like the code is inserting into calculation, but not inserting into value and calculation_value. For some reason it is stopping right after the first insert, before the loop. How would i be able to do an insert into ? i thought it would be too complex since i have functions and other things i am calling. If you think that approach is better i can definitely look into it.

Comment: @Littlefoot i found the error. you were right, i removed the first 'fetch' statement. it worked. thanks so much. sometimes its always the smallest mistakes that are the hardest to find.

Comment: The simplest reason why you don't insert into the 2nd and 3rd table is that loop exits because of `EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;`, i.e. cursor returned only 1 row; you fetched it, inserted into the first table, and the next FETCH (within the loop) didn't fetch anything, so - nothing got inserted.

Comment: thanks so much. in this situation i didnt need to fetch the cursor for the first insert. IN the event that i need to reference the same row of the same cursor in the outer and inner inserts, what do i need to do?

Comment: You already fetched it, so - reuse it.

Comment: thanks @Littlefoot is there a way i can vote your answer as the best answer even though these are comments? i really do appreciate the help. And no what i meant was if i put the fetch right after i open the cursor, my code doesnt work. (i deleted the fetch after opening of the LOOP

Comment: Cursors are *usually* used in the loop, following the principle: `open c1; loop; fetch c1; exit when c1%notfound; do something; end loop; close c1;` So - you shouldn't `open - fetch - loop` but `open - loop - fetch`. Or, even better use cursor FOR loop which is way easier to maintain (no open, close, exit statements should be used - Oracle handles that for you). As of (up)voting - don't worry about it; it's more important that you fix what's bothering you, but thanks anyway :)